# What do back end/server-side languages actually do?

Tags: javascript, database, node.js, websocket, backend

After grasping the fundamentals of  HTML, Javascript (frontend) and CSS, I wanted to learn about backend programming, what it is, what certain languages do, etc. Unfortunately I couldn't find any good sources of information about This (Links are welcome!). So I have a few questions.

I am  confused about backend programming in general. Mostly about what exaclty is needed to create a web app or something like a multiplayer web game.

- For example, if I learned node.js would I also need to learn mysql/sql to create a multiplayer game (Air hockey game with a player profile) .
- What about with Python/PHP?
- I don't really understand what roles the languages play in back end.

E.g: If I wanted to have a global hi-score menu on a game.

※Would I have to have a database?

※Would I have to use a back end language?

- I have also heard about  [Socket.io](http://socket.io) however the website is not very helpful for people that don't know much about this stuff (Like me!) So I don't really have any idea what it is - a framework, plugin, language etc. - or what it does. - on the website this is what it says:

  > Socket.IO enables real-time bidirectional event-based communication.

I have no idea what that means! An explanation would be helpful!

※ Also do I need a back end programming language or node.js to use socket.io?

I feel these are important things that unfortunately many (well at least me) people who have just started to learn javascript or any other languages do not understand.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to start learning PHP or - if you are familiar with JavaScript and the event-driven Architecture - Node.JS.

There are many step-by-step-guides and manuals for both.

Here are two of them:

- [Your first PHP-enabled page](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php)
- [Absolute beginners guide to NodeJS](http://blog.modulus.io/absolute-beginners-guide-to-nodejs)

Before you start to learn about Webservers and so on, you should understand what a website is, what a webserver is and what it does, and what a database is and what it does.

The Questions you should try to answer yourself are like:

- Where comes a website from (Who *generates* it and send it)
- How comes it to me (my browser)
- What does the browser do
- How is content generated dynamically
- What is a web server (e.g. Apache)

If you know these (and much more) basics it's easier for you to start learning Server Sided Languages like PHP

---

**Let's try to answer your current questions:**

> For example, if I learned node.js would I also need to learn mysql/sql to create a multiplayer game (Air hockey game with a player profile) .

No. You could also use things like MongoDB / Postresql / Text Files.
But yes, you should know, how to use data storages.

> What about with Python/PHP?

These are script languages which you can use for server sided programming (scripting). You don't have to learn them. You could use Node.JS.

> I don't really understand what roles the languages play in back end.

Please refer to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting).

> E.g: If I wanted to have a global hi-score menu on a game.
>   ※Would I have to have a database?

You *should* have a database

> ※Would I have to use a back end language?

Yes.

> [...] I have no idea what that means! An explanation would be helpful!

Then you shouldn't try to use it.
It helps you to communicate over so called *sockets*. The Client (Web Browser) could communicate with the Server, e.g. NodeJS (Socket.IO supports not only JavaScript) over a kind of channel.

> ※ Also do I need a back end programming language or node.js to use socket.io?

Yes.
But you could communicate to another socket on external systems without creating an own one.

Answer (score 1):

Sure let's break it down.

**Front end/client side**

This type of programming is what the **client** aka the user who visits the website will see. This will include your HTML, CSS, JavaScript. These all affect what the client sees.

**Back end/server side**

Now, the problem with front end is that there's no **persistent storage.** What's persistent storage? Well think of it this way. If you have an input box that asks what the user's name is and he/she types in "Anna" you would take it and store it in a javascript variable. As soon as the client closes the internet browser, the name "Anna" is lost forever! Well... that's not very useful if we want to store a list of usernames/passwords and everything else right?

That's where **persistent storage** comes in. Persistent storage is essentially your database which can be Relational and Non-relational... Examples of both are

Rel - MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle... and a few others

No-rel - MongoDB

I'm not really going to go into databases but just know that they exist to store your data... *indefinitely*. **Server-side languages** are there to interact with the database and the client. They're like the middle man. Frameworks such as Rails, Django, and (CodeIgniter, Laravel) PHP are what is responsible for creating a *framework* that will allow you to interact with the client side, database and serve your webpage.

For example, think of a blog. There's thousands of posts! It would be absolutely terrible if you had to write and copy paste your HTML code thousands of times for each blog page wouldn't it? Well instead of doing it that way, you could store all your individual posts in the database and use a **"template"** to **serve** your content. This way you'd only need to write your HTML code once (give or take) and the server will dynamically handle how to **view** your information.

This is the basis of what's called MVC or Model View Controller.
Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks that helped me deepen my understanding of how these programming languages and databases work and what they are! (Still looking for some specific answers!☺)

Comment: What kind of specific answers?

Comment: Like my question about socket.io - just looking for a clear up of what it is. Thanks!

Comment: Socket IO essentially simplifies web sockets. Websockets are what you typed up that they provide a persistent connection between a client and server that is _bidirectional_ For example a chatroom would use require this to allow client and server to send information to each other.

Comment: Oh ok thanks, so I still need a back end language and a data base to use it?

Comment: Having a database is up to you but most likely you would need a database. The serverside language you need is nodejs

Answer (score 1):

I understand why you are confused. I will first explain a little and then answer your questions.

#### What is a programming language?

JavaScript is a programming language and HTML and CSS are not. You can use most programming languages to instruct the computer to do anything you want. CSS and HTML on the other hand can only describe what a document looks like.

JavaScript is special in a way because all major browsers can run it. That makes it a very popular choice when writing code that is run in a website user's browser. Usually code written in a programming language either needs a program to run it or has to have separate versions for each operating system and processor type(64 bit x86, 32 bit x86, ARM).

#### There is no server side language

You can use any language on the server, because the code runs there, so the user doesn't need to install anything. Many people use PHP or Node.JS but you could use any language. I use Go for all my server side needs. So, yes, you need a server side language, but it can be any programming language.

Socket.io is a library for JavaScript. Libraries are pieces of software that people make so you can easily incorporate them in your program. Because it is for JS, you'd only be able to use Socket.io if writing JS.

You can actually code even client side with something else than JS, because there are lots of languages that can be compiled(translated) to JS. For example, Dart, Golang.

#### Do I need a database?

For global highscores you need to store the highscores on your server. Having them on the hard drive would be nice, because otherwise power loss would reset the leaderboard.

(Relational) Databases are a solution to that that works for everything, but can be a bit tedious in some cases and use too much cpu or hard disk time in others. To use databases you either need to learn SQL or use an ORM library.

#### Appendix: What does a web server do?

You might be familiar with a system where you put files into folders and you can then view them in your browser by going to the URL `mydomain.ending/path/to/filename`. *This is not how web servers actually work!*

When you go to that URL, the program running on your server gets a request that (among a lot of other information) tells that the user wants `/path/to/filename/`. The program can then do whatever it wants with that information. It could, for example send back a page with the text: "You wanted page /path/to/filename/".

To get the familiar file serving behavior, Apache is often used. That behavior is reasonable for example for serving images. The pages themselves are usually built out of pieces with blanks that can be filled in. For example you don't want to have to repeat you page's header for every single page.

If you really want to understand the details I recommend trying [the Go standard library](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/). With the library I linked, you can implement a server in two lines of Go code and serve files simply with a call to `http.ServeFile` while still maintaining complete control over your server. And if you want to build something bigger you can do the [filling in the blanks](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Thank you! That also helped lots! Will accept an answer tomorrow morning.